# User and Sales Rep Relationship - Polymorphic Relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

**Edit:** Looking back, I think my initial post was a little confusing and was lacking detail. So I'd like to reword it and provide some more information. Also, I've included a diagram example.

And please correct me if I have the wrong idea somewhere, but the idea is this:

- Users belong to one company, and a company can have many users.
- Users can belong to many roles, and roles can have many users.
- A company belongs to one company type. For example, there could be an "internal" company type, and a "distributor" company type.
- Based on the company's company type, the user roles will be different and non-overlapping. For example, if you are a distributor, you could have the roles of "Distributor Admin" and "Distributor User". The same applies for the internal type (Super Admin, Admin, Sales Rep, etc). This explains the relationship between company_type and roles: A company type can have many roles, and a role belongs to one company type.

So basically, if a user is part of a certain company, which is of a certain company type, that determines the roles that they can be assigned. If that makes sense so far, great!

The missing piece deals with how to handle a sales rep. Essentially, a sales rep is just a user that deals with other companies. I don't want them to be completely separate entities, because then I'd be duplicating information. I do have a sales rep role for the internal company type, but I'm not sure if that would tie in properly.

Does it make sense to do a 1-to-1 relationship between the user and sales rep (not done in the diagram), which means I could always just do a join to get the user information?

The end result will allow me to find all the sales reps for a company, and then all the companies for a sales rep.

Thanks in advance!

[image: erd diagram]

Comment: Do you have a diagram? It appears you just need two entities, people and companies, and many relationships between them: users, reps, primary reps, etc.,  based on the roles they play with each other.

Comment: @EmacsUser - which seems to imply a third table to represent the roles...

Comment: @BobJarvis - not just one but several tables to manage all the roles.